# Won't let me read in user input in after IF statement (homework)

Tags: c++, cin

I  am having some issues with my simple code of creating a dvd & software list to import into a csv file.
I have the output working fine but for some reason my program is skipping my first part of the code. If I take out the IF statement, that bit of code works so I am not understanding why.

my output looks like this:

> Would you like to add new media? Enter M for Movie or S for software: m
>   Enter the name of the Movie (20 Chararters or less)Name: Enter a rating for 
>   your movie 1-5:

I am not getting any errors in my compiler (Visual Studio 2013) and it does not allow me to input a name and skips right to rating.
Any explanations or suggestions would be appreciated as I want to fix this before I move on to adding more.

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){ 
string typeM = "movie";
string typeS = "software"; 
char answer, mediainput; 
int rating = 0; 
string dir, type;
string moviename,softname; 

do
{  
  cout << "Would you like to add new media? Enter M for Movie or S for software: ";
cin >> mediainput;
cout << endl;

if (mediainput == 'm' || mediainput == 'M')  
{   
cout << "Enter the name of the Movie (20 Chararters or less) \n Name: ";
getline(cin, moviename);
cout << endl;
cout << "Enter a rating for your movie " << moviename << " 1-5 ";
cin >> rating;
if (rating < 1 || rating > 5)
 {
  cout << "You must enter a number from 1 to 5. Enter a number rating: ";
  cin >> rating;
  cout << endl;
 }

ofstream outdata("DVD_Software_inventory.csv", ios_base::app);
outdata << moviename << "," << typeM << "," << rating << "," << endl;
outdata.close();
}

if (mediainput == 's' || mediainput == 'S')
{
cout << "Enter the name of the software (20 Chararters or less) \n Software   name: " << endl;
getline(cin, softname);
cout << "Enter the directory it is in \n Directory: ";
cin >> dir;

ofstream outdata("DVD_Software_inventory.csv", ios_base::app);
outdata << softname << "," << typeS << ",," << dir << "," << endl;
outdata.close();

}
cout << "\n\nWould you like to add more? Y/N ";
cin >> answer;
cout << endl;
if (answer == 'N' || answer == 'n')
 {
  cout << "** End of Program **" << endl;
  break;
 }


} while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');

system("pause");
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205251/stdcin-skips-white-spaces

Comment: Did you find your solution?

Comment: @stevesmd: Please accept my answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that while your cin >> statement ignores "\n" (the newline character), the character is still in cin's buffer. getline(), however, 
does not ignore the "\n" character.

The solution, therefore, is to explicitly tell cin to ignore the "\n" character:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
getline(cin, moviename);
```

(credit to http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/24470/)